# Position of voxelized instances with node mesh to volume

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a node setup, based on voxelization, that animates the removal of parts of an object depending on the time interval.

The goal is to use this together with the BlenderBim addon to simulate processes that make the object disappear (for example excavation or demolition).

[image]

The problem lies in the positioning of the instances in relation to the original object.

I noticed that for positions with integers the problem disappears, but with floats it returns.

I tried several things but was unsuccessful.

Any help to solve this problem or even the suggestion of another setuṕ will always be welcome.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you visualize the points cloud (after the "Distribute Points in Volume" by muting for example the "Instance on Points" node), you will see that whatever the position or the orientation of the object "Cube_Remove_parts" is, the "Mesh to Volume" node is putting points at fixed positions (that seem related to the world axes). One solution, not perfect, would be to move the points cloud such that its barycentre is coincident with the input geometry barycentre.

Comment: Or you can set the "Exterior Band Width" parameter of the "Mesh to Volume" node to the same value as "Voxel Size" to secure that the input geometry is completely "inside" this volume. The price to pay is that you could end up with "cubes" that are entirely "outside" of the input geometry, and thus, have no effect in the animation.